# Create a service for a Python script

Tags: python, service, systemd

I have a Python script containing a loop like this:

```
while True:
    if p.poll(waitTime):
        if j.process() == journal.APPEND:
            for entry in j:
                process_data(entry))
```

Currently, my service look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Journald shipper
Requires=systemd-journald.service
After=systemd-journald.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myScript.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem I currently have is the «start» command return a timeout.
That's logical because script is never finished but service never starts :(

So, I assume I'm doing things wrong.  Do I have to change the `.service` file to allow running script without waiting for it's end or do I have to change my «infinite» loop ?

And how can I do this ?

Comment: `if p.poll(waitTime):` is wrong. It is supposed to check if script has ended, but fails if the script fails with a zero return code. Do `if p.poll(waitTime) is not None:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think some additional information about your platform may be necessary to properly answer this.  I only say this because I am not personally familiar with the formatting of the service you have there.

However, if you want a pure Python way of doing this you could use the daemonocle package to create the service. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemonocle

alternatively, and the way that I normally accomplish this task, you can use a deamon skeleton such as this: 
https://gist.github.com/shawnrice/11076762
with this method you need to modify this template to run your script and install it into /etc/init.d after first run on the deamon script you should be able to use the standard "service  " to control your service.

Comment: Here is the script I'm trying to launch: https://github.com/chindit/journald-shipper  I'm running it on an ArchLinux up-to-date